# How to subdivide integer hash into ranges

Tags: go, fixed-point

I have unsigned 64bit number, representing mantissa, or fraction (which represent range from `[0..1)`, where `0.0` maps to `0` and `0xffffff..` maps to a number "just before 1.0")

Now i want to split this range into equal `buckets` - and to answer - given random number `key`, to which part of the range it will fall to?

Its easier to get from following code:

```
func BucketIndex(key, buckets uint64) uint64 {
    return uint64(float64(key) / ((math.Pow(2, 64) / float64(buckets)))
}
```

My attempt to "hack this over" - was to split 2^64 to two, like if I will reduce range to 32bit, and operate in 64bit in order to conduct math:

```
// ~=key / ((1 << 64) / buckets)
return ((key >> 32) * buckets) >> 32
```

but ranges stopped to be equal..
eg one third (`buckets==3`) will be at `0x5555555600000000`, instead of being at `0x5555555555555556`
thats sad story, so im asking do you know of a better methods of finding `(1 << 64) / buckets`?

Comment: Use a bucket size of `max / buckets`, rounded up, and bucket index will be `key / bucketSize`. Doesn't this suffice you?

Comment: @icza that's my question, how can you find max (which is outside uint64 range)

Comment: in other words, im interested in (MaxUint64+1) / buclets

Comment: think of it `key / (max / buckets)` if you will do `key * buckets / max` - you will get 0 immediately, because its like shifting all of the bits of uint64 by 64 positions to the lsb, clearing out all of its bits out of uint64 storage...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `buckets` is (compile-time) constant, you may use [constant expression](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constant_expressions) to calculate bucket size: constants are of arbitrary size. Else you may use `big.Int` to calculate it at runtime, and store the result (so you don't have to use `big.Int` calculations all the time).

#### Using a constant expression, at compile-time

To achieve an integer division rounding up, add divisor - 1 to the dividend:

```
const (
    max        = math.MaxUint64 + 1
    buckets    = 3
    bucketSize = uint64((max + buckets - 1) / buckets)
)
```

#### Using [`big.Int`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int), at runtime

We can use the above same logic with `big.Int` too. An alternative would be to use [`Int.DivMod()`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.DivMod) (instead of adding `buckets -1`), and if `mod` is greater than zero, increment the result by 1.

```
func calcBucketSize(max, buckets *big.Int) uint64 {
    max = max.Add(max, buckets)
    max = max.Add(max, big.NewInt(-1))
    return max.Div(max, buckets).Uint64()
}

var bucketSize = calcBucketSize(new(big.Int).SetUint64(math.MaxUint64), big.NewInt(3))
```

Comment: Interesting way, but I need at runtime, and scared that `big.NewInt` will require allocs and expensive conversions.. And I need fast! what do you think on working as with 2 64bit ints, doing `mult`, as in here? https://github.com/davidminor/uint128/blob/master/uint128.go#L72

Comment: @xakepp35 Yes, that'll likely be faster than `big.Int`. But note that if `buckets` has limited number of values, you can pre-calculate and cache the result bucket sizes, you don't have to calculate every time. Pre-calculating and caching will also outperform calculations with 2 64-bit integers too.

Comment: If value of `buckets` is small, you could store the results in a slice too, and use `buckets` as the slice index!

Comment: yeah, lut vs calc, depending on lot of factors. will check out how it's going..

Comment: Also note that storing and indexing a slice would also work if `buckets` is not small but could easily be transformed into a small number. E.g. let's say possible values of buckets are `100`, `200`, `300`. You could use a slice with 3 (or 4) elements to store the calculated bucket sizes, and index it with `buckets / 100`.